# How do I combine wkhtmltoimage with a JavaScript script using a Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wkhtmltoimage, phpwkhtmltopdf

I want to export an HTML document to an image using wkhtmltoimage on Windows 11.

The HTML document is built like this:

```
    ...
    <body>
        <div id="chart-id">
        </div>
    </body>
    ...
```

Before exporting the image, I need to call a JavaScript script that uses a Node.js module to build a chart within the . After that, the image should be exported.

Does anybody know how I can run the JavaScript script before exporting the image using wkhtmltoimage?

I'm trying to export an image using wkhtmltoimage from an HTML document that contains a canvas built by a JavaScript script importing a Node module.